# SFDX: Can you specify what to pull (or exlude) from a scratch org?

Tags: salesforcedx, scratch-org

When I did a sfdx force:source:pull, it pulled all the default apex pages and associated classes (things like resetting a password, etc.).

Is this because I have "hasSampleData":"true" in my scratch config file?

I don't want that as part of my package. How can I pull specific changes I make on the scratch org without getting all the rest? For example, I want to add some fields to a custom object, then pull that in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [.forceignore](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_exclude_source.htm) to prohibit things from syncing both directions. And yes, it's because you used hasSampleData set to true, or because you enabled specific features (e.g. creating a Site). Once you ignore the files, you can then safely delete them from your repo if they're already there.

Comment: Yes, I created a site. My app uses a REST endpoint that I have to manually created on the scratch org. (Don't think that can be pulled and packaged, due to the need to create a unique domain.)